# Prove that set contains at least two co-prime integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am asked:

> Prove that if n+1 distinct numbers are selected from the first 2n
>   positive integers {1,2,3,...,2n-1,2n} then at least two of the n+1
>   numbers are [co-prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) where n is a positive integer

I know 32 divides evenly into 64 and 96, but 32 is bigger than 16 and 20 so could not even divide. However 3+2=5 which can't get smaller.

How can I **prove** this?

Comment: It might be easier to show that two of the numbers are adjacent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the set into n disjoint subsets as such:

{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},...,{2n-1,2n}

By the pegionhole principle, if you select n+1 numbers 2 of them must be in one of the above subsets. These 2 are coprime. (This is beacuse for all positive integers  i,i+1 are coprime)